# How to export file or excel with Angular 2 (Front end) and Laravel (backend)

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic2, angular2-services, lumen

I'm trying export(download) file or excel with app Hybrid,but it's not working and not returns error.
This is my code with Laravel-lumen(Back end) and use

```
function getTransactionsExcel(Request $request){
$fecha_actual=Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d");
//return $fecha_actual;
$excel=Excel::create('List '.$fecha_actual, function($excel) use($fecha_actual)  {

    $excel->sheet('List', function($sheet) use($fecha_actual)  {


        $sheet->mergeCells('A2:E2');
        $sheet->row(2,(
            array('PLAZA BELLIN')
        ));


        $sheet->mergeCells('A3:E3');
        $sheet->row(3,(
            array('LIST')
        ));


})->export('xlsx');
```

}

in Angular2 (front-end )

in services use:

```
   import { Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

downloadExcel(){
      let url = 'your url/api'
      return this.http.get(url,{headers:'pass your header',responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
      .map(response=>response.blob())
      .catch(error=>{return Observable.throw(error)})
  }
```

I'm use a buttom for download  the file. If Someone have an answer I would appreciate!
Thanks.